# Linkify is linking invalid links. Why? Is there an option to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using Linkify: https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-linkify

The issue is that Linkify is linking invalid links for example:

**valid**

```
http://techcrunch.com/
```

**Invalid**

```
checkthisouthttp://techcrunch.com/
```

Any ideas on how to prevent linkify for linking non-links? Given Linkify is dated, anything better available? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Linkify https://github.com/cowboy/javascript-linkify only tests if the URL scheme matches `[a-z\\d.-]+://`.

Which does match both of your examples: `checkthisouthttp://techcrunch.com/` and `http://techcrunch.com/`.

It would be simple to change it so that it restricts the URL scheme to only a set list (such as `http`, `https`, etc.)
by replacing line 73 `SCHEME = "[a-z\\d.-]+://",` of `ba-linkify.js` with a regex that matches only those schemes.